# Comparing prolog anonymous variables

Tags: prolog, prolog-anonymous-variable

I have a series of facts in prolog that contain the anonymous variable `_`.

```
fact(a, _).
fact(b, _).
fact(c, _).
```

and i have some rules that take in lists of these facts:

```
f([H | T]) :- H == fact(a, _),
              % stuff %
              .
```

however this is not working. The rule is not going past the first clause `H == fact(a, _)`. What am I doing wrong? Is there a different operator for equality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should probably use `=/2`:

```
1 ?- H == fact(a,_).
false.

2 ?- H = fact(a,_).
H = fact(a, _G0).
```

the difference is that `==/1` *checks* if the two terms are equal and non-instantiated variables (that have a different name) are treated as different. On the other hand, `=/2` unifies the two terms, instantiating as required.

If you use an instantiation pattern in the head (`f([fact(a,_)|T]):- stuff.`) it has the same behaviour with `=/2`